# php subscribing to rss feed

Tags: php

I'm trying to add rss feeds to my website.  There is a different rss feed for different topics.  What i don't know how to do is allow the user to subscribe to an rss feed?  I want to put a link that says 'subscribe to rss feed' or just the rss icon.  `Feed.php` has the rss feeds, so depending on the `$id` a different rss feed will  be displayed.

Feed.php

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"); 

include "database.php";

$id = $_GET['id'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$position = $_GET['position'];

$database = new Database();
$database->opendb();
$items = $database->rssfeed($id,$position,$type);
$database->closedb();

?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel>
<?php

echo $items;

?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

What way do i allow the user to subscribe to an rss feed?  For example a feed url on my website for a topic may be `www.example.com/feed/12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the application/rss+xml mime type. Browsers and plugins automatic detect your feed, and enabled the subscribe. Try it on google reader or som.